# PowerShell: filter string list

Tags: powershell

This seems like a very basic thing to do, but I am new to PowerShell and can't figure this out or find an example online...

I am trying to filter a list of strings. This list of strings is the result of a "svn list" command (Subversion list of repository files), like:

```
svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY
```

I have tried

```
svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY | where {$_ -like "stringtomatch"}
```

and this does not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might consider using -match instead of -like. -Match is more powerful (regex based) and will work like you were initially expecting:

```
svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY | where {$_ -match 'stringtomatch'}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY | where {$_ -like "*stringtomatch*"}
```