# Powershell filter list

Tags: powershell

Question: how do I filter 3 strings at the same time  `'stringtomatch1'` and `'stringtomatch2'` and `'stringtomatch3'` ?

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297777/powershell-filter-string-list) lets you filter only 1 string at a time:

```
[svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY | where {$_ -match 'stringtomatch'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-match` takes a regex as an argument, so just use the logical OR operator, `|`

```
svn list -R PATHTOREPOSITORY | ? {$_ -match 'stringtomatch1|stringtomatch2|stringtomatch3' }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm

Comment: @bestili:Give the man some credit and accept his answer, then.